# Using non simmetrical button background images

Tags: android, android-layout

Id like to have a button shaped like a cloud. A 9 patch might be unusable since every time I create large borders around my cloud image, I get warnings about "bad patches" in the 9 patch tool. Using 1px borders gives weird results too [1](http://hooffzaken.nl/junk/tmp_res.zip). When replacing my resource with the btn_default from api 4 I get expected results, ruling out xml issues.

Without using 9 patches, wrap_content seems to work no more, growing the image to 100% width regardless of content. The 9 patch used is shown below.

I wouldn't mind some distortion, as long as content does not overflow. What would be the best solution?

I am not allowed to post images yet, apparently. Please see
[zip containing screenshots and 9patch](http://hooffzaken.nl/junk/tmp_res.zip)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice question.

I think there is no way to use those images and you might need to change them, but I will leave you some tips or things I would try:

- To avoid overflow you will need to define the fill area. You can try just adding a fill area but not a scale area. If this works, you will have the cloud image with the text inside it.
- Remember that 9patches scale up and not down.
- Here is a [link](http://radleymarx.com/blog/simple-guide-to-9-patch/) with a very good explanation of how everything works.
- If nothing worked so far I would ask the designer to create a new image resource with a stretchable area. For instance, having cloud shape just in the corners.

Comment: Thanks for that, didn't know 9patches could not scale down. It must be possible to use this image tho, since I am willing to accept some distortion